# How to set custom URL in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url, routes

I need in MVC4 in C#...

{id}.example.com or

{id}.example.com/{controller}/{action}

Or

In localhost how can I test it.

I means, can I debug this code in below format ...

{id}.localhost:51782 or

{id}.localhost:51782/{controller}/{action}

Please explain this in full steps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle your requests with "virtual" URL, for example `{user}.example.com` and internally update httpcontext path using `httpContext.RewritePath()`. Finally you will have two types of URIs.

1. Virtual: {id}.example.com/{controller}/{action}
2. Real: {id}/{controller}/{action}

Handling is possible in `Application_BeginRequest` inside your `Global.asax.cs` file

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
   var domainHandler = new DomainsHandler(Context);
   domainHandler.Handle();
}
```

And example of DomainHandler:

```
public class DomainsHandler
{
    private readonly HttpContext httpContext;

    public DomainsHandler(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    public void Handle()
    {
        httpContext.RewritePath(path);
    }
}
```

Rewriting logic inside Handle() method is up to you.